# Updating selected entities updates all entities in ngneat/elf repository

Tags: angular, angular-state-managmement

I'm facing an issue where I try to update an entity in the store but every entity gets updated instead.
Now I have defined the entities and their ids as such:

```
const { state, config } = createState(
  withEntities<IDossier, StateGlobConf.ENTITY_ID_KEY>({ idKey: StateGlobConf.ENTITY_ID_KEY }),
```

and later when I wish to update and entity I proceed to do the following (as per [Documentation](https://ngneat.github.io/elf/docs/features/entities/entities#updateentities)):

```
updateDossier(id: IDossier[StateGlobConf.ENTITY_ID_KEY], dossier: Partial<IDossier>): void {
  store.update(updateEntities(id, dossier));
}
```

As far as I understand the only entity that should be updated is the one with the passed id, or if I am doing something wrong, I don't understand what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown code was good, but the problem was the type I was sending. So my model was structured as such:

```
{
    StateGlobConf.ENTITY_ID_KEY: number
}
```

meaning the key was named `StateGlobConf.ENTITY_ID_KEY` but its value was of different type (type number).

The fix looks like:

```
updateDossier(id: number, dossier: Partial<IDossier>): void {
  store.update(updateEntities(id, dossier));
}
```